# Inferring individual types when using union type generics (extending react component props)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to define a wrapper React component that accepts a number of predefined properties. The presence and value of one of the properties (`tag`) should also determine if additional properties are available. The react component will act as a wrapper for the provided `tag` component, which will be rendered with any props that aren't handled specifically by the wrapping component. If `tag` is omitted it would be ok for the wrapper to still accept and forward the unhandled props to the child component, but without providing any types (a simple `Record<string, any>` or similar would do).

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to prevent Typescript from generating a union of all possible attributes when the `tag` prop is omitted.

A minimal reproduction of the issue is available on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-generics-tag-props-8vlet?file=/src/index.tsx). The issue I'm trying to solve is further explained in it, but **TL;DR:**

```
<Field tag="textarea" name="test" cols={10} /> // cols is correctly typed
<Field tag="input" name="test" cols={10} /> // cols is correctly marked as invalid
<Field name="omitted" cols={10} /> // cols is typed here even though it's not a prop on <input>
```

**Excerpt of the code:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export type FieldTagType = React.ComponentType | "input" | "select" | "textarea";

type TagProps<Tag> = Tag extends undefined ? {}
  : Tag extends React.ComponentType<infer P> ? P
  : Tag extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements ? JSX.IntrinsicElements[Tag]
  : never;

export type FieldProps<Tag extends FieldTagType> = {
  /** Field name */
  name: string;
  /** Element/component to createElement(), defaults to 'input' */
  tag?: Tag;
};

function Field<Tag extends FieldTagType>({
  name,
  tag,
  ...props
}: FieldProps<Tag> & TagProps<Tag>) {
  return React.createElement(tag || "input", {
    name,
    id: name + "-id",
    placeholder: name,
    ...props
  } as any);
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    {/*
      <textarea> supports the `cols` attribute, as expected.
    */}
    <Field tag="textarea" name="textarea" cols={10} />
    {/*
      <input> doesn't support the `cols` attribute, and
      since `tag` is properly set typescript will warn about it.
    */}
    <Field tag="input" name="test" cols={10} />
    {/*
      When `tag` is omitted it appears that FieldTagType
      is expanded into every possible type, rather than falling
      back to not providing any additional properties.
      This results in `cols` being included in the list of defined props,
      even though it is not supported by the `input` being rendered as fallback.

      Is it possible to modify the typings of TagProps/FieldProps/Field
      so that omitting `tag` will not include any additional properties,
      but also not error?
      Eg. TagProps are expanded to `Record<string, any>`
    */}
    <Field name="omitted" cols={10} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: Maybe try `function Field<Tag extends FieldTagType = "input">` setting the default type of Tag to "input"

Comment: @JacobSmit thanks for the suggestion! See [my response to the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798999/inferring-individual-types-when-using-union-type-generics-extending-react-compo#comment116352630_65802207).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Field` with no `tag` property in its argument, this does *not* cause the compiler to infer `"input"` or even `undefined` for the `Tag` generic parameter.  Since `tag` is an optional property, an undefined value for `tag` can apply to *any* valid choice of `Tag`.  For example, you could specify `Tag` as `"textarea"` and still leave the `tag` property out:

```
Field<"textarea">({ name: "xyz", cols: 10 }); // no error
```

It's unlikely for that to actually *happen*, of course.  Anyway when you leave out `tag` the compiler has no idea what `Tag` should be, and just defaults it to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints), `FieldTagType`.

If you would like it to default to `"input"` instead, you can set a [generic parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults):

```
function Field<Tag extends FieldTagType = input>({
// default here ----------------------> ~~~~~~~ 
    name,
    tag,
    ...props
}: FieldProps<Tag> & TagProps<Tag>) {
    return React.createElement(tag || "input", {
        name,
        id: name + "-id",
        placeholder: name,
        ...props
    } as any);
}
```

That doesn't affect the inference for your other cases, but when `tag` is omitted, now you get the empty `TagProps<undefined>` for `props`, and the desired error:

```
    <Field name="omitted" cols={10} /> // error!
    // -----------------→ ~~~~
    // Property 'cols' does not exist on type
    // 'FieldProps＜"input"＞ & TagProps＜"input"＞'
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwCwAUKJLIiutnjACIDyAsnCIlylLgFoAJiVqNGWAB4t4MAJ5gscAGLAsAG0kAVZAHND6zQF5GcW3AA+mKjAB0AYRKQAdli8xzGjZ2jmTAXmAArjBkQbYhqPpY1LEO5DCKMMhiMQyMahpwxiYACsRgqAA8RQB8cJaFpnAZvpLoEV6SWARhWJIpAPxwAN4AvikAXA0mTQrpHRzO7p4QPn4BWBVhBFhQcMXVA3sTUzNzrXAA1liqEARwAFIAygAaLgCSflBhqMC4AKJ6LAgXwwVCHJ6vD4wL5eH7-QHAvyoADaRQAuscfAA3Hb0XIMRTKOD5TQ6fSSUoQcpVRrNebaXQGIrrWr1IYpAD0CCQZIMcC8yGBiA5KQFwMmqGhYRMeLscC5SABQJBHNwy1WKggcFwYnSSsRMAAFABKAA0cE6BGQET0oOJWoA5GFIjAHcKUpkTP1JkU8SM8YwCO18MAVgzyTTpnTzryjKZ1nVyM6omRqob2Qw5WKsKaPaZc5m7C5i2AymCGCNJrHKdSanAAGRTGuVGrG4YpSgwCJQLxOLguHU4PUIkGGz0OELJ6LmjNyrOCnMpOXASSTbNwADU5HEK7IBbndjAejwWAAFhADDs1wv9we4MWXKWqeW5SN2CgvKpjX65AxYxUyHSWYshwVN035BdJjIBRVAALz3bUL1QSYAEYAAY4BGb95Q5fktR2YgoF-NVYXgYgIBgfUQUTaRcAiA0XBMLBKJHPwACFVDeSRDQoCAKLIb9GE4fA+H4FxKA6HZDRSCphNcR4pXwfgIE6A5CwPCpY2JUxLEAjIQOQMgIOBXSgMybJEL0VBLCGdC3w5NS7zgTTGUkbSTF0qcjOzUysElIy1Ssmy7PlWoOVwgjoAAQiXOxwrgcREqS5KUtSlLACTCOAAD8cqy2LbHimsdjUOAHUC1A3WkPy8PgRRgElOAwxJfKcNK6sy0AHH-QnCFNADx-hsm067qXTIXqHRalzyWMrBdJIYAYHSSQAqQ4K0PssKIqgQiYvUud4rSg7Esy3K8t2uVCrKYrVFK8rKogaqvAomZ6vgJqLBa+KHXa58uq8-rGyKZtfp66Ixt-OUKg5OSXAUr4lJUrBqlvWxyJY5U-EYQT8UYIA)

Comment: Thanks for the write-up, much appreciated!
I completely forgot to mention that I did try assigning `'input'` as the generic parameter default, which like you wrote does solve the overall issue. The only drawback is that this makes it harder to discover the component specific props in the intellisense/LSP attribute/prop completion lists (at least on my vim setup) due to the high number of added input attributes. I have a feeling that there's no way to improve on this though, so unless anybody has a way to address that I'll mark this answer as the correct one.

Comment: As an example, if providing a `tag` was required to include the additional attributes I could start with `<Field |` and then only see the field props as suggestions until I explicitly added `tag="input"`, after which suggestions would include `input` attributes as well.

Comment: Well it's possible that there's something better, but I don't know that I can commit to spending more time looking at it.  Good luck.